# Extra Escape Characters added to string From Web Service

Tags: xml, string, wcf, escaping, asp.net-web-api

I have 2 services, a WCF service and a Web Api service. The web api service just calls a method on the WCF service and returns the result. The return type of the method on the WCF service is a string in Xml format, for example:

```
 "<Person Name=\"SomeGuy\" />"
```

The "\" are to escape the " characters. But the return string from the web api service is:

```
 "<Person Name=\\\"SomeGuy\\\" />"
```

It seems to treat my string as a string and therefore escapes my escape characters. When I try to convert the result to Xml it obviously fails because it is trying to convert a string that looks like the first string.

How do I get the second service to return the string 'as is' and not modify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I changed the return type to HttpResponseMessage and explicitly set the return type:

```
var resp = new HttpResponseMessage()
{
    Content = new StringContent("<Person Name=\"SomeGuy\" />")
};
resp.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml");
return resp;
```

This meant that the return value would be treated as Xml and not a string.